# Initialization of static data member

Tags: c++, storage-duration

Why does default initialization of static data member not occur? In the following example

```
struct data_member
{
    data_member(){ cout << "data_member\n"; }
    ~data_member(){ cout << "~data_member\n"; }
};

struct Y
{
    static data_member m;
    Y(){ cout << "Y\n"; }
    ~Y(){ cout << "~Y\n"; }
};

Y y; //call constructor of Y
```

but if we delete `static` specifier from `data_member m` it will be default-initialized.

```
struct data_member
{
    data_member(){ cout << "data_member\n"; }
    ~data_member(){ cout << "~data_member\n"; }
};

struct Y
{
    data_member m;
    Y(){ cout << "Y\n"; }
    ~Y(){ cout << "~Y\n"; }
};

Y y; //call Y() and data_member()
```

Comment: Because you didn't provide a definition for `m`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious 9.4.2/6: _Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables_. This implies that default-initialization must be performed.

Comment: That's exactly right, as long as you provide a definition for it which you have not done.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Why does non-static data member initialize?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Non-static members obviously need to be constructed when the object is constructed. Static member declarations don't cause construction because it just declares the member's existence.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's a link time issue. Are you still struggling with your compiler implementation? I'd suspect you could have been better off, just using the LLVM clang c++ frontend and extend whatever you want based on the already correctly parsed AST as mentioned earlier.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, The non-static data member declaration is a definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static member must be defined outside the class definition. It will be initialized (can be default initialized too) at that time.

The following description from the draft standard about `static` member variables should explain why it is not default initialized in the class declaration.

> **9.4.2 Static data members**
>
> 2 The declaration of a `static` data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified `void`. The definition for a `static` data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition. In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the `static` data member shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator.

Answer (score 2):

`static` data members are *declared* in the `class` definition.  They need to be *defined* (once) outside of that, usually in the corresponding `cpp` file:

```
data_member Y::m;
```

this is where you'll see it's default ctor called.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Y
{
    static data_member m;
    Y(){ cout << "Y\n"; }
    ~Y(){ cout << "~Y\n"; }
};
```

This only *declares* `m`. For all the compiler knows, `Y::m` is defined in another translation unit. Since static data members are one-per-class, you have to be able to declare them without defining them, or you won't be able to put the class definition in a header file without violating the One Definition Rule when including the header in different translation units.

```
data_member Y::m;
```

This defines m and [will cause a constructor call](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ba0278f6551959f).

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer:
With class members it's like with functions.
We have declarations and definitions.
You "declare" their existence @class level and "definition" is made by constructor.
With static member its more complex. They are not "instance related" and constructor will not "define" them. You have to do it by your own outside of class:

```
Type CLASS::member;
```

Btw it's quitebad practice to use static members.

Use a static function instead :

```
class Foo{
public:
     Type &getMember(){
         static Type member;
         return member;
     }
};
```